# Print the columns that have outliers in dataframe

Tags: python, statistics

I have a dataframe (250×25) with 20 columns having numeric values (mix of int64 & float64).

I want to print the columns which have outliers in them.

```
mydata = pd.read_csc('data.csv')
df = mydata.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
Q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
df = df[((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
print(df.columns)
```

I found through excel that I have only 4 columns with outliers. I am not sure how to get them.

Comment: you printed it no? The code should be ok. Can you explain in a bit more detail what the issue is?

Comment: No. I am getting all columns. While I need only those 4 column names which have the outliers.

Comment: see answer.. you need to call out the column names first

Answer (score 0):

This is the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(111)
mydata = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(5,4)),columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
df = mydata.select_dtypes(include=np.number)

    c1  c2  c3  c4
0   0.612170    0.169070    0.436059    0.769262
1   0.295325    0.149163    0.022478    0.420224
2   0.238682    0.337656    0.990712    0.237726
3   0.081193    0.669600    0.621243    0.274254
4   0.466221    0.118368    0.073958    0.900774
```

There should be no outliers. We try your boolean:

```
((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
```

This returns the row-wise boolean which is wrong. You need to do it on the other axis, and also subset on the columns:

```
df.columns[((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=0)]
```

Let's put in 2 columns with outliers, should return c3 and c4 :

```
df.iloc[1,2] = 1.8
df.iloc[2,3] = 2.5
df.columns[((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=0)]

Index(['c3', 'c4'], dtype='object')
```